# Get class fields by name

Tags: scala

For example my case class is

```
case class Test(id: String, myValues: List[Item])

case class Item(id: Long, order: Long)
```

and I get string value like

```
val checkValue: String = "id"
```

I want sort Tests by items and I want it to look like

```
val test= Test("0", List(Item(0, 14), Item(1, 34))

val sortedItems = test.myValues.map(_.*checkValue*).sorted
```

Its about get field of class like `someInstanceOfClass.checkValue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala is not an interpreted language, therefore you can't just use strings as variable names. The easiest way to solve your problem is to map the string value to the variable:

```
scala> def get(item: Items, str: String) = str match {
     |   case "id" => item.id
     |   case "order" => item.order
     | }
get: (item: Items, str: String)Long

scala> test.myValues.map(get(_, checkValue)).sorted
res0: List[Long] = List(0, 1)

scala> test.myValues.map(get(_, "order")).sorted
res1: List[Long] = List(14, 34)
```

Of course there are more ways to solve the problem. You could use Reflection to read the name of the variable at runtime. In case you already know at compile time the name of the variable you want to read, you could also use macros to generate the code that is doing what you want. But these are both very specialized solutions, I would go with the runtime matching as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to rethink how you're going about this.  What good does the string `"id"` actually do you?  If you just need the capability to pull out a particular bit of data, why not use a function?

```
val f: Item => Long = _.id
```

Do you not want to have to type the function type over and over again?  That's fine too; you can use a method to request the compiler's help filling in the type arguments:

```
def pick[A](x: Item => A) = x
val f = pick(_.id)
```

Now you can use `f` anywhere you would have used `"id"`.  (You can even name it `id` instead of `f` if that will help, or something that reminds you that it's actually a function that gets an id, not an id itself, like `idF` or `getId`.)